# Intersection of 2 binary trees throws Stack Overflow error

Tags: java, binary-tree

I am trying to intersect two binary trees, and create a new binary tree with the nodes that are the same, but the following creates a stackOverflow error. Can anyone help me?

```
private OrderedSet<E> resultIntersect = new OrderedSet<E>();

public OrderedSet<E> intersection(OrderedSet<E> other) {
    OrderedSet<E> result = new OrderedSet<E>();
    if (other.root == null || root == null)
        return result;
    else if (height() == 0 && other.height() == 0
            && other.root.data.equals(root.data)) {
        result.insert(root.data);
        return result;
    } else {
        intersection(other, root, other.root);
        result = resultIntersect;
    }
    return result;
}

private void intersection(OrderedSet<E> other, TreeNode root1,
        TreeNode root2) {
    if (root1 == root2) {
        resultIntersect.insert(root1.data);
    }
    if (root1 == null || root2 == null) {
        return;
    }
    intersection(other, root1.left, root2.left);
    intersection(other, root1.right, root2.right);
}
```

*Edit*

I feel like this is closer to how I need to do it, but I still get the error.

```
private OrderedSet<E> resultIntersect = new OrderedSet<E>();

public OrderedSet<E> intersection(OrderedSet<E> other) {
    OrderedSet<E> result = new OrderedSet<E>();
    result = resultIntersect;
    return result;
}

private void intersection(OrderedSet<E> other, TreeNode t) {
    if (other.contains(t.data)) {
        resultIntersect.insert(t.data);
    }
    if(t.left != null)
        intersection(other, t.left);
    if(t.right != null)
        intersection(other, t.right);
}
```

Comment: how big are your trees? Could you possibly be hitting the maximum recursion depth?

Comment: The trees I'm testing are very small, 4-5 nodes.

Comment: @Test
 public void testIntersection() {
  OrderedSet<Integer> bst = new OrderedSet<Integer>();
  OrderedSet<Integer> bst2 = new OrderedSet<Integer>();
  
  bst.insert(5);
  bst.insert(2);
  bst.insert(4);
  bst.insert(6);
  
  bst2.insert(5);
  bst2.insert(2);
  bst2.insert(6);
  bst2.insert(9);
  
  assertEquals("2 5 6", bst.intersection(bst2).toStringInorder());
 }

Comment: It looks like the private OrderedSet<E> is causing the error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Binary Search Trees](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271645/java-binary-search-trees)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the specific problem but there are some issues.

1. why is "other" passed into the second intersection (it's never used)?
2. shouldn't you return after you do the insert into the set?
3. shouldn't you be passing in the local OrderedSet (called `result`) and inserting into it, rather than global variable?
4. shouldn't you be comparing the data of root1 and root2 rather then the nodes themselves?
5. the second return is superfluous
6. you dereference the roots *before* you test for null
7. The initial testing is unnecessary

Cleaning up those flaws, I get:

```
public OrderedSet<E> intersection(OrderedSet<E> other) {
    OrderedSet<E> result = new OrderedSet<E>();
    intersection(result, root, other.root);
    return result;
}

private void intersection(OrderedSet<E> result, TreeNode root1,
        TreeNode root2) {
    if (root1 == null || root2 == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (root1.data == root2.data) {
        result.insert(root1.data);
    }
    intersection(result, root1.left, root2.left);
    intersection(result, root1.right, root2.right);
}
```

I don't know if this will work, but it's closer

Answer (score 0):

A stack overflow error suggests that there's recursion that's not bottoming out before the stack limit is reached.  The chief suspect is the `private void intersection` method.  If the inputs are correct binary trees, then the condition `(root1 == null || root2 == null)` should be reached at some point -- but this might be a long time for a very large, unbalanced binary tree, or never if the "binary trees" are buggy and have a cycle somewhere.  Either case could be a reason for the overflow.

I'd also point out that the condition `if (root1 == root2)` in the same method is probably not doing what it's intended to: the parameters `root1` and `root2` are probably not the same object, so that condition will almost certainly be false.  Some other `equals()` based comparison is probably more appropriate.

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing now that the whole thing is wrong. How would I just go through a tree? I could use .contains to see if one tree has the nodes from the other tree.

Comment: You've got the right idea, just some difficulty in the details.  @Malvolio has some great suggestions; I'd recommend implementing them and trying again.  I'd also look at whether your binary trees are just too large for the recursion; if so, then you can try rewriting the recursive algorithm as an iterative algorithm.