# Intersecting 2 binary trees - throws Stack Overflow error

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Intersection of 2 binary trees throws Stack Overflow error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271206/intersection-of-2-binary-trees-throws-stack-overflow-error)
>   [Java Binary Search Trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271645/java-binary-search-trees)

I need to return a new OrderedSet that contains the overlapping elements of the two binary trees. I think it is the private OrderedSet that is throwing the error, at least that is what eclipse is telling me.

```
private OrderedSet<E> resultIntersect = new OrderedSet<E>();

public OrderedSet<E> intersection(OrderedSet<E> other) {
    OrderedSet<E> result = new OrderedSet<E>();
    result = resultIntersect;
    return result;
}

private void intersection(OrderedSet<E> other, TreeNode t) {
    if (other.contains(t.data)) {
        resultIntersect.insert(t.data);
    }
    if(t.left != null)
        intersection(other, t.left);
    if(t.right != null)
        intersection(other, t.right);
}
```

**EDIT

I can't seem to get it to return correctly. How can I get the private method to return the result correctly?

```
    public OrderedSet<E> intersection(OrderedSet<E> other) {
    OrderedSet<E> result = new OrderedSet<E>();
    result = intersection(other, root, result);
    return result;
}

private OrderedSet<E> intersection(OrderedSet<E> other, TreeNode t, OrderedSet<E> result) {
    if (other.contains(t.data)) {
        result.insert(t.data);
    }
    if (t.left != null && t.right != null)
        return intersection(other, t.left, result) + intersection(other, t.right, result);
    if (t.left != null)
        intersection(other, t.left, result);
    if (t.right != null)
        return intersection(other, t.right, result);
    else
        return result;
}
```

Comment: Most likely, your tree is badly formed and loops back to a previous intersection. Add logging to every invocation of `intersection` and see where it deviates from what you expect.

Comment: It immediately fails, is there something wrong with how I wrote the private variable?

Comment: Have you tried stepping with a debugger?

Comment: In case there isn't a poorly formed tree like David suggests you might want to (temporarily?) simplify things and make resultInterset public and remove the intersection(OrderedSet<E> other) method since it doesn't seem to do much (other than return resultIntersect) and might be confusing in the rest of your code since it's named the same as your main intersection algorithm method. Also I'm assuming there is other code that turns one tree into an OrderedSet that you aren't showing?

Comment: The public intersection method needs to be there, it is for an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

I answered in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271645/java-binary-search-trees/11272364#11272364), but for completeness, here it is again.

---

Although you don't mention it, and your posted code did not include it, I'm guessing `OrderedSet<E> resultIntersection` is a field in `OrderedSet<E>`.  In which case when you create a new instance of `OrderedSet<E>` it creates another instance of an `OrderedSet<E>` to assign to `resultIntersection`.  That then has it's own `resultIntersection` that needs an instance of `OrderedSet<E>` creating, and so on...

The fix would be to remove `resultIntersection` and find some other way of implementing `intersection`.  It's generally bad practice to have methods passing data around by manipulating shared state when it's not necessary, as it makes the logic more difficult to follow and can lead to multi-threading issues.

Comment: That makes sense, I didn't think about it like that. I'm having trouble changing it, so that I am able to return the OrderedSet.